# How can I add image to ListView when I set it to details?

Tags: c#

How can I add image to ListView when I set it to details ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for instance:

```
  ImageList imgList = new ImageList();
  imgList.Images.AddStrip(bitmap);
  this.listView1.StateImageList = imgList;
```

Comment: use SmallImageList instead, and rememeber to set the imageindex of the listview item

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/876b6517-7306-44b0-88df-caebf3b1c10f) might answer your question.