# C# .net Windows Forms Listview with image in Detail View

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I want something like this develop using C# .net for Windows Forms. (ListView Details View). Putting a Image is the problem.

[image]

Help me ..!!

Thank You

Yohan

Comment: There are a ton of articles and documentation out there with samples. A quick google search should show you [several](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983754%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) [good](http://programmerslog.wordpress.com/2008/07/18/using-listview-control/) ones... or even similar [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3388025/how-can-i-add-image-to-listview-when-i-set-it-to-details) questions and answers.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Hope that the following code can help you out.
using `C#`

```
ImageList il = new ImageList();
il.Images.Add("test1", Image.FromFile(@"c:\Documents\SharpDevelop Projects\learning2\learning2\Koala.jpg"));

listView1.View = View.LargeIcon;
listView1.LargeImageList = il;
listView1.Items.Add("test");

for(int i = 0; i < il.Images.Count; i++)
{
    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
    lvi.ImageIndex = i;
    lvi.Text="koala 1";
    listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
}
```

Running this kind of code can get you the image and the text in a listview.
For further more details, refer to this [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winforms/thread/876b6517-7306-44b0-88df-caebf3b1c10f)

Comment: Format your code with the {} button on the editor toolbar.  Tell the OP how to use an ImageList in the designer.

Comment: @Hans: Thanks for your comment. i did not get what you meant by the OP.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look at this Code Project entry.

[Extended ListView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/EXListView.aspx?df=100&forumid=266091&exp=0&select=1427247)

Comment: Seems overkill for what the OP requested but an interesting reference