# How can I make a scrollabe image list in C# Windows Form?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, picturebox

I need to create thumbnails list of pictures located on web.
I would like also to add CheckBox to make thumbnails choose able.
I'm trying to load pictures from urls to ListBox

```
// from form design file:
System.Windows.Forms.ListBox listBoxPictures;

// from main file
foreach (Photo albumPhoto in album.Photos)
{
  PictureBox albumsImg = new PictureBox();
  albumsImg.LoadAsync(albumPhoto.URL); // URL is string
  CheckBox selectedPhotoCheckBox = new CheckBox();
  listBoxPictures.Items.Add(albumsImg);
  listBoxPictures.Items.Add(selectedPhotoCheckBox);
}
```

It doesn't work, there are no images appear in ListBox.
What am I doing wrong?
How can I make a scrollabe image list in C# Windows Form?

Comment: is this similar to what you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255579/c-sharp-net-windows-forms-listview-with-image-in-detail-view ?

Comment: or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472897/c-sharp-can-i-display-images-in-a-list-box?

Comment: You can't add images to a ListBox.  Consider a ListView instead, it needs an ImageList for its images.  No support for asynchronous loading, you'll need to add that feature yourself.

Answer (score 0):

what is wrong is that you have to wait load completed of picture

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //make your loop here

        pictureBox1.WaitOnLoad = false;
        pictureBox1.LoadCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(pictureBox1_LoadCompleted);
        pictureBox1.LoadAsync(albumPhoto.URL);
    }

    void pictureBox1_LoadCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //now your picture is loaded, add to list view
         CheckBox selectedPhotoCheckBox = new CheckBox();
         listBoxPictures.Items.Add(albumsImg);
         listBoxPictures.Items.Add(selectedPhotoCheckBox);
    }
```

Comment: Nice tip thank you, but I do not see images thumbnails in the list.

Comment: if you use WPF no problem to add image but like said Hans Passant in Winforms you could not and you have to use listview