# Download image thumbnails and show them in ListView C#

Tags: c#, image, listview, thumbnails, listviewitem

I'm trying to download thumbnails and show them in a listview. What am I doing wrong ?

ListView loads but it doesn't show any thumbnails.

```
 using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            foreach (var thumb in imgFiles.Item1)
            {
                byte[] data = webClient.DownloadData(thumb);
                using (MemoryStream imageData = new MemoryStream(data))
                {
                    Image img = Image.FromStream(imageData);
                    thumbList.Images.Add(img);
                }
            }
        }

 for (var i = 0; i < thumbList.Images.Count; i++)
        {
            ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
            lvi.ImageIndex = i;
            lvi.SubItems.Add("test");
            lvi.SubItems.Add("test1");

            lvi.Text = i.ToString();

            listViewLinks.Items.Add(lvi);
        }
        listViewLinks.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent);
```

[image: ListView loads without images]

Comment: Can you see the images if you just put them in the window, outside of the grid?

Comment: Did you set the ``ImageList``? Have a look at the very bottom of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What is `thumbList`? You have to use proper view and fill proper image list in given `ListView`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5255732/1997232).

Comment: thumbList is ImageList, @RandRandom :Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with the below code.

```
listView1.SmallImageList = thumblist;
ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
lvi.SubItems.Add("A");
lvi.SubItems.Add("B");
lvi.SubItems.Add("C");
lvi.ImageIndex = 2; // this will display YourImageList.Images[2] in the first column
listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
```

Are you able to getting ImageList.

Comment: This is assuming `listView1.View = View.SmallIcon`.