# Images are not showing in Listview using .NET

Tags: c#, .net, listview

I am able to get this result successfully from the sample code here
[C# .net Windows Forms Listview with image in Detail View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255579/c-sharp-net-windows-forms-listview-with-image-in-detail-view) using .NET Framework however the same code and form setup using.NET6.0
does not work i.e. the image does not show in the listview. I tried many many suggestions until I realized that the .NET was causing my issues.

Am I missing something for .NET to show the images in the listview?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<string> _list = new();
    ImageList serviceLogoList = new ImageList
    {
        ImageSize = new Size(32, 32),
        ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit
    };


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        initializeListView();


        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"\resources"); //change and get your folder
        foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles())
        {
            try
            {
                this.serviceLogoList.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(file.FullName));
            }
            catch
            {
                //log error
            }
        }

        foreach (var str in _list)
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
            item.Text = str;
            item.SubItems.Add("OK");
            item.ImageIndex = 0; //tried 1,2,3,4,5 as well
            listView1.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
    private void initializeListView()
    {
        _list.Add("Test1");
        _list.Add("Test2");
        _list.Add("Test3");

        listView1.View = View.Details;
        //listView1.LargeImageList = serviceLogoList;
        listView1.SmallImageList = serviceLogoList;
        listView1.Columns.Add("Name", 100);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Status", 100);
    }
}
```

Here is the code as requested. This code works when .NET Framework 4.7.2 is selected instead of .NET 6.0 (LTS). This code is courtesy of a post on StackOverflow but I can't find the link at the moment. The code works based on "Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)" but not on "Windows Form App"

Add a listview control to the form called listView1. Everything else is done in the code behind.

[image: .NET Framework] [image]

Comment: Could you provide some code and actually show us what does not work? Are you getting an error? Or they simply don't show in the Listview? We need a little more info, it is not quite clear what your issue is

Comment: View.LargeIcon requires the ListView.LargeImageList property to be set, setting SmallImageList produces items without images.  In 4.7.2 as well.

Comment: Sorry, I edited it since I am using "View.Details" , I have included the output from each type of project

Answer (score 0):

An update on this. It seems the control I was using which was from the [MaterialSkin](https://github.com/leocb/MaterialSkin/issues/126) (link takes you to an issue raised by someone else) package does not support images. I changed out the control for a Winform one and everything works as intended. I created a blank form, added one listview control named listview1, and changed the view type to details. I will style the control to match the rest of my UI.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ImageList imageListSmall = new ImageList();
        imageListSmall.Images.Add(Bitmap.FromFile("D:\\subtract.png"));
        imageListSmall.Images.Add(Bitmap.FromFile("D:\\add.png"));
        listView1.SmallImageList = imageListSmall;

        listView1.Columns.Add("Item Column", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);

        listView1.Items.Clear();

        ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem("item1", 0);
        listView1.Items.Add(item1);
        item1 = new ListViewItem("item2", 1);
        listView1.Items.Add(item1);
       

    }
```